# Apache HTTPClient does not make more than 2 connections

Tags: java, httpconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've been trying to implement connection pooling for my application using Apache HTTPClient (v4.1). The problem is that the client always makes only two connections when run, though there are enough threads running parallel. I have been trying to modify the code for a while now, but nothing has helped yet.
I'm using `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` for connection pooling and set the `MaxTotal` and `DefaulMaxPerRoute` to values I want.

Is there anything that comes to your mind first that I might want to check?

Here's that code segment that I use to create the client.

```
DefaultHttpClient createClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

    params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(60000));
    params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(60000));
    params.setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 6443));
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

    ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
    cm.setMaxTotal(2 * maxConnections);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnections);

    HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("localhost");
    cm.setMaxForRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), maxConnections);

    HttpHost sdpTargetHost = new HttpHost("webserviceIP", webservicePort, "https");
    cm.setMaxForRoute(new HttpRoute(sdpTargetHost, null, true), maxConnections);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
}
```

The client returned by this function is used in `Runnables` managed by a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The Runnables use the client, and has these lines:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
....
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

From what I know, the `EntityUtils.consume(entity)` will notify the connection manager that the connection is no longer used, and thus will release the connection to be used by other threads. So I'm guessing the connection management is alright.

I guess I've provided enough info, please tell me if I'm to add anything more.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597447/threadsafeclientconnmanager-not-multithreading/7603315#7603315

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot HttpClient problems is by turning on its wire / context logging. Follow the instructions of the logging guide http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html and activate context logging for connection management / request execution. This will help you see the stats of individual per route connection pools and will also help you see whether connections get correctly released back to the connection manager.

Comment: @oleg Is this likely to still be a problem?  It seems like the fix was arbitrary, and shyam concluded with " I presume this probably is some sorta bug in the HttpClient 4.1 API.".  I'm seeing a similar issue and don't want to jiggle code.

Comment: There is nothing that needs fixing. One needs to configure connection pool to allow more than 2 concurrent connections per route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK. I've found the solution, thanks to [oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) for pointing out the logging, and to google and all the forums.
 All I had to do was define the class with only the connection manager, and then set HttpParams using HttpClient.setParams(). So the code will look something like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient createClient() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 6443));

    ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(registry);
    cm.setMaxTotal(maxConnections);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnections);

    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("webserviceIP", webservicePort, "https");
    cm.setMaxForRoute(new HttpRoute(targetHost, null, true), maxConnections);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
}
```

And right before using the client,

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = createClient();
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(60000));
params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(60000));
params.setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true);
httpClient.setParams(params);
```

There apparently is no difference in the code *logically*, but this fixed my problem. I presume this probably is some sorta bug in the HttpClient 4.1 API.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to set this option in cm

```
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnections);
```

It was necessary to do so:

```
ConnPerRoute perRoute = new ConnPerRouteBean(100);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, perRoute);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 15000);
```